# Gostaria de adicionar o conteúdo de uma célula na mensagem do Scrip

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Criei um script que quando chega determinada data ele envia uma mesagem, só que nessa mensagem eu gostaria de  adicionar o conteúdo de uma célula da planilha onde o script esta executando esse

```
function EnviaEmail(){
  var resultado,linha,data;
  var assunto = "XXXXXXXXXXX<conteudo da célula> ";
  var mensagem = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"<conteudo da celula>;
  var aba = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(nomeAba);
  var colunas = aba.getLastColumn();
```

Answer (score -2):

Não ficou muito clara a diferença entre as variáveis `assunto` e `mensagem`, mas para adicionar o conteúdo da célula você pode usar

```
function EnviaEmail(){
  var aba = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(nomeAba);
  var conteudoCelula = aba.getRange(celula).getValue();
  var resultado,linha,data;  //também não entendi o propósito disso
  var assunto = "XXXXXXXXXXX" + conteudoCelula;
  var mensagem = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" + conteudoCelula;
  var colunas = aba.getLastColumn();
```

Não tenho certeza se a sintaxe `"texto" + variável` é válida, mas esse é o princípio básico.

Uma dica para futuras perguntas: sempre disponibilize uma cópia da planilha (ou a própria planilha, caso não haja problema), e um [exemplo minimamente reproduzível] (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), além de exemplos com as entradas e saídas desejadas montadas manualmente, caso seja possível.